# Find the threshold for this probability expression?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, limits

I have the function
$$
P_{n,k} = (1-\frac{\binom{n-1}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}})(1-\frac{\binom{n-2}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}})\cdots (1-\frac{\binom{k}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}}).
$$

When $k$ is a constant, I have $P_{n,k}\to 0$, when $n\to \infty$. When $k=n$, I obviously have $P_{n,k} = 1$.

Can you find the threshold $k^{\star} = k(n)$, i.e., the function of $n$, for which $\lim_{n\to\infty}P_{n,k} = 0$, if $k<<k^{\star}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} P_{n,k} = 1$, if $k>>k^{\star}$?

Comment: You'll get better answers if you give more context. What have you tried so far, what approaches do you think might be useful here, etc. If you got the problem from homework, what topics is the class covering recently? Otherwise, what makes you interested in this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Note that, for $j = 1, \ldots, n-k$,

\begin{align*}
1 - \frac{\binom{n-j}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}}
&= 1 - \prod_{p=0}^{k-1} \frac{n-j-p}{n-p}
= 1 - \prod_{p=0}^{k-1} \left( 1 - \frac{j}{n-p} \right) \\
&\geq 1 - \exp\biggl( - \sum_{p=0}^{k-1} \frac{j}{n-p} \biggr) \\
&\geq 1 - \exp\biggl( - \int_{0}^{k} \frac{j}{n+1-x} \, \mathrm{d}x \biggr) \\
&= 1 - \left(1 - \frac{k}{n+1}\right)^j
\end{align*}

From this point on, we assume that $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ is a fixed constant and the limit is taken in such a way that $n \to \infty$ and $k/n \to \alpha$. Then it is not hard to check that the above bound limplies

$$ \liminf_{n\to\infty} P_{n,k} \geq \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 - (1 - \alpha)^j \right). $$

On the other hand, for each fixed $j$, we have

\begin{align*}
1 - \frac{\binom{n-j}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}}
&= 1 - \exp\Biggl[ \sum_{p=0}^{k-1} \log \left( 1 - \frac{j}{n-p} \right) \Biggr] \\
&= 1 - \exp\Biggl[ -\sum_{p=0}^{k-1} \frac{j}{n-p} + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{j^2}{n} \right) \Biggr] \\
&\to 1 - e^{j \log(1-\alpha)}.
\end{align*}

So, for each fixed $J$,

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} P_{n,k} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{j=1}^{J} \Biggl[ 1 - \frac{\binom{n-j}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}} \Biggr] = \prod_{j=1}^{J} \left( 1 - (1 - \alpha)^j \right). $$

Since the limsup does not depend on $J$, we may replace this upper bound by its limit as $J \to \infty$. Then, combining both the lower and upper bound, we conclude that

$$ \lim_{\substack{ n\to\infty \\ k \sim \alpha n}} P_{n,k}
= \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 - (1 - \alpha)^j \right). $$

Below is the graph of the right-hand side as a function of $\alpha$:

[image: Graph]

(The plot markers represent the values of $P_{n,\mathtt{round}(\alpha n)}$ when $n=25$, which is already pretty close to the corresponding limit value as $n \to \infty$.)

Furthermore, noting that $k \mapsto P_{n,k}$ is increasing in $k$, we can check that this result extends to the boundary case $\alpha = 0, 1$ as well.

- If $k/n \sim 0$, then $P_{n,k} \to 0$.
- If $k/n \sim 1$, then $P_{n,k} \to 1$.